# Paging the top_hits aggregation in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Right now I'm doing a top_hits aggregation in Elastic Search that groups my data by a field, sorts the groups by a date, and chooses the top 1.

I need to somehow page this aggregation results in a way that I can pass through the pageSize and the pageNumber, but I don't know how.

In addition to this, I also need the total results of this aggregation so we can show it in a table in our web interface.

The aggregation looks like this:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "top_artifacts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "artifactId.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_artifacts_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{
              "date": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, you should be able to do pagination through a [Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html). You can still pass your `size` parameter in your pagination, but your `from` would be the key for the bucket.

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "top_artifacts": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "artifact": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "artifactId.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
        , 
        "size": 1, // OPTIONAL SIZE (How many buckets)
        "after": {
          "artifact": "FOO_BAZ" // Buckets after this bucket key
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it is not clear for me the `after` field, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @sant016 If your cardinality for `terms` is 100. You say `size: 10`, you receive a response that contains an field `after_key`, in that is the last `bucket._key` for the bucket aggregation. You then use that in your `after` field to get the next 10. NOTE: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_order